# Summation over divisors Proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if f is multiplicative, and if n = $p_{1}^{e_{1}} \cdots p_{r}^{e_{r}}$ is the prime factorization of n, then $\sum_\limits{d|n}\mu (d)^2f(d)$ = $\left ( 1+ f\left ( p_{1} \right ) \right )\cdots\left ( 1 + f\left ( p_{r} \right ) \right )$

Attempt:

The only non-zero terms in the sum are when the divisor is of the form $d = p_{1}\cdots p_{t}$, where $p_{i}$ are all distinct.

For these terms $\mu(d)^2$ = 1.

Now since f is multiplicative, for these divisors we have f(d) = f($p_{1}$)$\cdots$f($p_{t}$)

This implies that $\sum_\limits{d|n}\mu\left(d\right)^2f\left(d\right)$ = $\sum_\limits{d|n}f\left(p_{1}\right)\cdots f\left(p_{t}\right)$

I don't know if this is the right way to approach the problem, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand out the product $(1+f(p_1))\cdots (1+f(p_r))$, the result is the sum of $f(d)$ over all square-free divisors $d$ of $n$. Since $\mu^2(d)=1$ if $d$ is square-free and $\mu^2(d)=0$ otherwise, this is the same thing as $\sum_{d|n}\mu^2(d)f(d)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, except that the right hand side you are getting should be thought of as
$$\sum_\limits{d|n}f\left(p_{1}\right)\cdots f\left(p_{t}\right)=f(1)+\sum_{i=1}^{t}f(p_i)+\sum_{\stackrel{i,j=1}{i < j}}^{t}f(p_i)f(p_j)+\sum_{\stackrel{i,j,k=1}{i < j<k}}^{t}f(p_i)f(p_j)f(p_k) + \dotsb .$$
Now the right hand side is same as the product you have.